# How to pass 2x-resolution image to wxBitmapButton in OS X?

Tags: wxwidgets

My app has a toolbar which is normally 64 pixels height. On OS X (with a retina display) the toolbar's height still equals to 64 (logical) pixels.

If I pass 64x64 bitmap when creating a wxBitmapButton I get a blurry image (which is expected), so I need to pass somehow a 128x128 bitmap.

When I pass it, it's just shown cropped without proper scaling. So how can I use wxBitmapButton to show high-quality bitmap?

Comment: what is you wx version? is your application have the necessary settings in the info.plist?

Comment: I have the following high DPI related values in Info.plist: <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key><true/><key>NSPrincipalClass</key><string>wxNSApplication</string> in Info.plist and the wxWidgets version is v3.1.4.

Comment: @ababo, I face exactly the same issue, have you found the solution?

Comment: Not yet, just switched to other problems for now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old question by now, but there is finally a good answer to it now if you're using the latest versions of wxWidgets from Git or 3.1.6+ once it will have been released.

The answer consists in using [wxBitmapBundle](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap_bundle.html) which is basically a smart container for bitmaps to be used in different resolutions/at different DPI scale factors. In the simplest case, which is sufficient under Mac, you just need to create a bundle from the two bitmaps, to be used at normal (or 100%) and high (or 200%) DPI by using `wxBitmapBundle::FromBitmaps(bmpNormal, bmpHigh)` and pass this object to `wxBitmapButton::SetBitmap()`.

This also works with `wxToolBar` tools, `wxStaticBitmap` and other (although not yet all) classes. And the bitmap bundle can be created from resources, which is especially convenient under Mac, as you can just have `normal.png` and `normal@2x.png` files in your application bundle (which has nothing to do with `wxBitmapBundle`, it's just an unfortunately overloaded term) `Resources` subdirectory.